# How can I improve the speed at which QGIS 2.4 handles network data? (Seems much slower than 2.2 - even with small datasets)

Tags: qgis, network

I recently downloaded and installed QGIS 2.4 Chugiak on a Windows 7 64-bit machine with a quad core processor and 8GB RAM.

I'm having a few problems using datasets of all sizes from a **network** drive - the data is slow to render and there is an annoying low-pitched "beep" each time I zoom in/out. In the previous release (2.2), this network data would render almost instantly for small datasets with no sounds.

I've also noticed that opening the attribute tables for this network data is very slow. E.g. a dataset with just 91 records takes almost 30 seconds - something that was almost instant in QGIS 2.2 Valmiera.

Using the dataset on a local drive removes the problems, though this is not an option as we have several members of staff working on the same datasets and want to avoid having multiple file versions all over the place!

Have any network settings been changed from 2.2 to 2.4?

Comment: Do you get the sound when using local files?

Comment: No. The sound only occurs when using the network data in QGIS 2.4. It plays repeatedly whilst opening the attribute table until the data is displayed - generally once or twice whilst re-rendering which is completed quicker than opening the attribute table.

Comment: Strange.  Others have reported this also but QGIS doesn't do anything sound related.  I wonder if it's a Qt bug of some sort.

Comment: Looks like the sound might be a separate issue - just installed QGIS 2.4 on my home PC and tried loading data from the network there. Same speed issues but without the low-pitched beeps whilst loading. Very slow to render / open attribute tables unless the data is on a local drive. Looks like we're sticking with 2.2 for now then until someone solves the issue!

Comment: I wonder if the slow speeds and sound are somehow related.

Comment: With the same configuration I have new QGIS version (2.4) installed in a SSD disk but when access data from second HDD (SATA) I face the same problem as described above. I can hear "click" sound in my SSD and really slow reading/rendering even in small data. (Should I open a new post?)

Comment: Wow... after some tests just realized that my problem happens when data is stored in a folder named with special character (in this case: é) from ANY local disk.

Comment: I have tracked this down to a bug in GDAL 64bit (the beep).  See this ticket here: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/10746

Comment: Just re-read that article. I've renamed the file "C:\Program Files\QGIS Chugiak\bin\gdalplugins\ogr_SOSI.dll" as suggested and re-opened QGIS 2.4. The buzz/beep sound is gone, but the slow refresh is still a problem. Getting closer!

Comment: Have exactly the same problem, including the Beep. I copied the shapes from the network to my desktop, projected into Qgis, started editing, no beeps or performance problems. As soon that i project the shape that is on the network, in the same project, the beep starts, even the zoom in and out produces a beep. Performance gets decreased when editing, sometimes its impossible to edit because everytime i move the mouse it gets stuck, beeping, then, seconds later returns to normal, move the mouse again, same problem... Guess i will be starting to Work on the Desktop, then copy the shapes to offic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Renaming the plugin "ogr_SOSI.dll" to something like "ogr_SOSI_old.dll" as Nathan suggested removed the buzz/beep sound for me. The speed issues seem to have gone too now - not sure if it was related to that or just some issues with our IT systems. All is good for now!